# How to prevent data from being recycled when using pd.merge_asof in Python

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

I am looking to join two data frames using the pd.merge_asof function. This function allows me to match data on a unique id and/or a nearest key. In this example, I am matching on the id as well as the nearest date that is less than or equal to the date in df1.

Is there a way to prevent the data from df2 being recycled when joining?

This is the code that I currently have that recycles the values in df2.

```
import pandas as pd
import datetime as dt

df1 = pd.DataFrame({'date': [dt.datetime(2020, 1, 2), dt.datetime(2020, 2, 2), dt.datetime(2020, 3, 2)],
                    'id': ['a', 'a', 'a']})

df2 = pd.DataFrame({'date': [dt.datetime(2020, 1, 1)],
                    'id': ['a'],
                    'value': ['1']})

pd.merge_asof(df1,
              df2,
              on='date',
              by='id',
              direction='backward',
              allow_exact_matches=True)
```

This is the output that I would like to see instead where only the first match is successful

[image: Targeted Outcome]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Given your merge direction is `backward`, you can do a mask on duplicated `id` and df2's `date` after `merge_asof`:

```
out = pd.merge_asof(df1,
              df2.rename(columns={'date':'date1'}),    # rename df2's date
              left_on='date',
              right_on='date1',                        # so we can work on it later
              by='id',
              direction='backward',
              allow_exact_matches=True)

# mask the value
out['value'] = out['value'].mask(out.duplicated(['id','date1']))
# equivalently
# out.loc[out.duplicated(['id', 'date1']), 'value'] = np.nan
```

Output:

```
        date id      date1 value
0 2020-01-02  a 2020-01-01     1
1 2020-02-02  a 2020-01-01   NaN
2 2020-03-02  a 2020-01-01   NaN
```

Comment: This solution is simple and works perfectly. Thank you!